# What is the regular expression for matching *text*?

Tags: python, regex

What is the regex to match `this is *some text*.` but not `this is \*another \*text`. The regex is supposed to match the texts between the asterisks.

Comment: What did you try? Also, what language are you trying this in?

Comment: Are you trying to extract the asterisk-enclosed portion, or are you just trying to find if the text complies with this format?

Comment: Please provide additional examples that would be expected to match / not match or clarify your question.

Comment: I am trying to find the locations of the asterisks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pattern = "\*(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*)\*"
re.findall(pattern, "this is *some text*.") // return 'some text'
re.findall(pattern, "this is \*another \*text") // return nothing
```

For replacing '*' with '$':

```
subpattern = "(\*(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*)\*)"
re.sub(subpattern, r"$\2$", "this is *some text*.") // return 'this is $some text$.'
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that. What if I wanted to find the index of *. My goal is to replace the asterisk's with some other symbol such as $

Comment: `re.sub("(\*(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*)\*)", r"$\2$", "this is *some text*.")`

Comment: If `text = 'abc *xyz* *abc* *def*'` and if I `findall()` against the pattern `pattern = \*(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*)\*'` the result is `['xyz', 'abc', 'def']'` which is what I am looking for. However if I change my char of interest `*` to `_` then I am guessing the new pattern should be `pattern = "_(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*)_"` (please correct me if I wrong). Now when I `findall()` the text, `text = 'abc _xyz_ _abc_ _def_'` against the new pattern the result is `['xyz_ _abc_ _def']`. Why am I not getting `['xyz', 'abc', 'def']`?

Comment: In the previous pattern we allowed spaces within the text enclosed between asteriks. So the pattern matches as long it can (comprehending spaces).
If u don't want spaces anymore inside the matching text, the new pattern will be: `(_(?:\w+)_)`.